# Is an edit that changes mobile links to desktop links a meaningful edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, ethics

Some websites, like Wikipedia, use an `m.` prefix to distinguish between the mobile and the desktop version. Mobile users often automatically get the mobile version when navigating to the desktop version, while desktop users usually don't automatically get switched when visiting the mobile version.

The mobile version is rarely designed for viewing on a desktop, leading to wasted screen real estate and visually less interesting articles. Some mobile versions even deliberately don't show certain content that is available on the desktop version (for example, the mobile version of wikipedia does not show the categories of an article).

I have no idea what the ratio is between mobile and desktop users is for the SE network, but even if we have more mobile than desktop users, I still think that, since mobile users often get redirected anyway when visiting a site, changing links from mobile versions of a site to desktop links is not exactly trivial. I certainly think they're as meaningful as spelling and grammar edits.

Comment: On SO that problem exists in [797](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fm.) posts. If there is nothing else to fix in the post I would consider changing it a waste of effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say to this the same thing as is generally said to "is this edit worth it" questions:

- **If a post is perfect except for this:** then go ahead. I probably wouldn't bother, myself, just because it's pretty trivial, but if you're feeling driven, and particularly if you have enough rep to not enter the suggested edits queue and bother other people with it, it's a nice thing to fix.
- **If the post has other things that  need fixing:** then go ahead, as long as you fix those other things as well. If you're improving everything you can think to in a post, it make sense to me to have this be one of those things.

Note that the second case is *almost* always the actual one. I'm pretty sure I've never seen a post that was perfect in every single way.

Long story short, yes, this is a reasonable edit. But I wouldn't just pop onto every post with that issue, edit it to include the desktop link, and leave. Make sure you address everything you can think of, but if that's one of the issues you find, I see no reason to *not* make the fix.

Note, of course, that, as you said, this is pretty much the same as what I would say if you were asking about minor grammar or spelling mistakes.